# Preventing pop-up dialogs when connecting an MTP device

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, android, udev, mtp

I'm using Lubuntu 14.04 with a Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.3. Each time I connect my phone via USB, I get the following dialog:

> Unable to open MTP device '[usb:002,023]'

A few moments later, I get the "Removable medium is inserted" dialog, prompting me to open in File Manager. After that, the phone is connected and fully accessible.

So MTP works. The problem is that I plug in my phone to charge every time I sit down, and unplug it every time I step away. Dismissing these two dialogs every time is a pain.

I would think the "Removable medium" dialog is the easier candidate. How do I tell Ubuntu to take no action and stop prompting me?

For the MTP error, all the discussion I can find is for people who can't get MTP working at all. For me, it's working, but only after throwing this initial error.

I've verified that my device is present in `/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules` .

Comment: you could try xkill and then select the window. Although this isnt a solution but save me lot of ill effects

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs
```

Executing this command will install the necessary tools and the error won't appear. A complete reboot might be needed.